# Martingale and quadratic covariance

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, martingales

Let B a standard Brownian motion.
$$M^i_t=\int_0^t\phi^n_t \, dB^i_s = \sum_{i=1}^{K_n-1}U_{t_{i-1}^n}(B_{t_{i}^n}^i-B_{t_{i-1}^n}^i) $$
$$N^i_t=\int_0^t\psi^n_t \, dB^j_s = \sum_{i=1}^{K_n-1}V_{t_{i-1}^n}(B_{t_{i}^n}^j-B_{t_{i-1}^n}^j) $$
In a proof that i'm following i'm not able to understand why, if I prove that $M^i_tN^i_t$ is a martingale, then $[M^i,N^j]_t=0$ for all $t>0$ . Where $[M^i,N^j]$ is the quadratic covariance)

Comment: For continuous local martingales $M$ and $N$, $[M,N]$ is the unique finite variation process that is $0$ at $0$ and such that $MN - [M,N]$ is a continuous local martingale. You just need to use the uniqueness part of that statement.

Comment: By the definition or property of quadratic covariance, $[M,N]$ is the only finite-variation process such that 
$$MN-[M,N]$$
is a martingale. Here if we prove that $MN$ is a martingale then $MN-0$ is a martingale so the result follows.